# Duplicates with condition in R

Tags: r, duplicates, conditional-statements

I need to find duplicates with x column="a" and column x="b" in R. What  R function can I use?

```
ID x
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 c
2 b
3 a
4 a
4 b
5 c
```

output:

```
ID x
1 a
1 b
4 a
4 b
```

These seems don't work.

```
Data <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2), Value = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
FindDups(Data, Vars = 'ID')
```

Comment: did you try "duplicated()" , "unique()"  , or  "==" ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to select rows where an `ID` has both `'a'` and `'b'` values?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(all(c('a', 'b') %in% x) & x %in% c('a', 'b'))

#     ID x    
#  <int> <chr>
#1     1 a    
#2     1 b    
#3     4 a    
#4     4 b
```

Same thing can be done in base R :

```
subset(df, as.logical(ave(x, ID, FUN = function(x) 
           all(c('a', 'b') %in% x) & x %in% c('a', 'b'))))
```

as well as `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[all(c('a', 'b') %in% x) & x %in% c('a', 'b')], ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this. Create a variable to store the number of elements equal to `a,b` and then filter. Here a code using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(var=sum(x %in% c('a','b'))) %>%
  filter(x %in% c('a','b') & var==2) %>% select(-var)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID x    
  <int> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     1 b    
3     4 a    
4     4 b
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L), x = c("a", 
"b", "c", "c", "b", "a", "a", "b", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `sum` in `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(sum(c('a', 'b') %in% x) == 2, x %in% c('a', 'b'))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   ID [2]
#     ID x    
#  <int> <chr>
#1     1 a    
#2     1 b    
#3     4 a    
#4     4 b
```

---

or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .I[sum(c('a', 'b') %in% x) == 2 & x %in% c('a', 'b')], ID]$V1]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L), x = c("a", 
"b", "c", "c", "b", "a", "a", "b", "c")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```